# Where MS Domain store the infromation

Tags: php, dns

I need to get user information like username, name, permissions and etc. from MS Domain because I want shared user login for my domain and website (in another server). Is this a way to do that? :)

Comment: You mean active directory? You can use the ladp interface; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721083/active-directory-lookup-via-php

Comment: Ops sure AD :) I think the only way is using LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPF, SenderID or DKIM to authenticate a domain.